# I keep getting this error every time i run my code through the validator

Tags: html, css, attributes, spacing, adobe-brackets

I am coding HTML5 And CSS3 In Brackets for a college class assignment and when I am done with a page of code I like to go to vaildator3.org to make sure my code doesn't have any errors and if does then fix them and then run it again well I have ran it 4 times already and it keeps giving me this error that says "Error: No space between attributes." and the specific thing that it's talking about is this code that I have which is

```
<li><a href="aboutme.html"class="current">About Me</a></li>
```

and its saying that I can't have spaces between attributes and I have tried to go back and fix it and I even retyped this line of code and it still gave me the same error but I don't know how to fix this....

Comment: It's as it says - you don't have any spaces between your attributes. Try `<a href="aboutme.html" class="current">About Me</a>`.

Comment: Obviously there is no space in-between `html"` and `class=` - Did you try adding one there?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, there's no space between your attributes.

Change your code to this:

`<a href="aboutme.html" class="current">About Me</a>`

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to put the blank space between href attributes and class

you wrote this

> `<li><a href="aboutme.html"class="current">About Me</a></li>`
> then change to
> `<li><a href="aboutme.html" class="current">About Me</a></li>`

the problem will be solved